# Different ViewModels in PartialView and View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net MVC Core 2.0 application where I have _PartialView which takes Model named "CommonViewModel",  View_1 which takes Model named "DashBoardViewModel" and View_2 which takes model named "PackageViewModel". The Data in CommonViewModel is same for both the views View_1 and View_2.

In short, Consider a web application where _PartialView displays navigation menus and View_1, View_2 are two different web pages. _PartialView must be common for View_1 and View_2.

Note: navigation menus in _PartialView comes from database and contents of View_1 and View_2 are different.

I need help for implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the partial view with the common model and inherit that common model to different Models.